# "Je ne mords pas " or "je ne mord pas"

Tags: grammaire, orthographe, conjugaison

As far as I understand, since *mordre* is an *-re* verb, its conjugation in the "je" form is "je mords". But I have seen written, and Google translate confirms, "je ne mord pas".

Where did the *s* go?

Comment: Plenty of people mistakes on the Internet and Google translate is not reliable and cannot be trusted to confirm anything.  There are plenty of reliable sources you could have used to check how to conjugate a verb. http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/mordre.php,  http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-french-verb-mordre.html.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "I have seen written" is too vague and Google Translate is not a source that can "confirm".

Comment: Ah, the stories we could tell about what we have "seen written". Some of us edit what we see written for a living. :) Trust your grammar books and teachers, at least till you're comfortable enough in your French to critically examine what you find. That is, not "Why is Google Translate right and my book wrong?" but "Hey, isn't GT wrong? Perhaps I should stop taking it on faith."

Comment: @Laure Voyez-vous l'humour? "Plenty of people mistakes on the Internet"

Answer (score 6):

Google Translation can be wrong sometimes, in this case the valid conjugation is :

```
je ne mords pas
```

because :

```
Je mords
Tu mords
Il/Elle/On mord
Nous mordons
Vous mordez
Ils/Elles mordent
```